# How can I call my REST API get method without hard-coding a URL?

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm in the process of developing a REST API, with the idea of creating a website (Java Webapp) that will call this API, and a mobile application that will also call the API.

However, despite being nowhere near publishing any of the above online (to my own domain), I can't see how my application would work if deployed anywhere other than my computer.

The reason for this is because I have hard-coded instances of "localhost:8080" all over the shop!

For example:

**server.xml** (I am using Tomcat 8.0.20):

```
<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
...
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

**SomeClass.java** (This is one of the class files in my web application, not my REST API)

```
final WebResource webResource = client.resource( "http://localhost:8080/api/get" );
```

The above WebResource is from the Jersey Client 1.8 dependency, and requires a hard-coded URL to access my API at the specified path.

This all works fine locally, but surely when I deploy the API/Webapp into production this will stop working, right?

I guess I'm looking for one of three solutions here:

1. Some implementation allowing me to access my REST API using relative paths (so I only have to specify "/api/get" for example). I am planning on deploying both the API and the Webapp on the same domain in production, so I assume this wouldn't be an issue(?)
2. Some method of dynamically determining the appropriate base URL, which will work regardless of the environment that I deploy the app in
3. Any other suggestions that would make my application bulletproof in this regard

I tried option 2 using

```
HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()
```

and although it returns the correct path (at least locally - http://localhost:8080), I keep getting the following exception:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
```

so I have steered away from using this method for now.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: That exception appears to have nothing to do with your URL problem - look at the stack trace to see where it's coming from.

Comment: That is the only line in the exception (there is no trace, it appears as though it has been suppressed). None of my HTML/XSL files actually contain a <hr> element anyway. My research tells me this exception is caused by an interrupted response resulting in not-well-formed XML

Comment: Well if there's no stack trace, that sounds like there's a diagnostic problem somewhere - it's not clear where you're seeing that exception at all.

Comment: That exception is being displayed in my Console in eclipse, when I attempt to access the API locally, which is running in Tomcat. Anyway, I'm not after a solution for the exception issue, I'm more just interested in an alternative to hard-coding "localhost" everywhere throughout my application, in preparation for one day going live with it

Comment: Well I typically like to understand one error before moving on to the next, but... basically you'll want to be able to have different config files. For example, Spring should let you have a property file for it to load configuration from - when running locally you could use localhost, and at other times you could have the production URL.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea Jon. Can you please write up an answer explaining how to do this (or provide a link with a detailed explanation)? i.e. how would my application know which config file to use? Would this be a manual code change at the time of deployment?

Comment: It would be a properties file shipped as part of the deployment. It's too long since I've written a Tomcat or Spring app to remember the details, but at this point it's really just general webapp configuration - I'd expect any good tutorial on the relevant technologies to include a section about it.

Comment: Thanks Jon I'll do some research around this now that I know the sort of thing I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call to a standard Webservice or a REST API you will need to publish your application in Internet.

It means that you can´t use localhost, you will need a EndPoint that will be accessed from all the mobile or web aplication that use your API.

This Endpoint is what you are writting in your client

```
client.resource("http://www.myApi.org/api/get");
```

And this base URL (www.myApi.org) it must be known by all the clients that use your API.

Comment: I like this answer, but then how can I test it locally?

Comment: To test locally you could do several things depends on your project. 

Based on an application with a Tomcat sever and an Android application to test it, if I were you I would have a server in local and I will generate a especial android apk to test localy with your local endpoint. After testing everything, i would have the production server with the tested code, and a final android apk with your production endpoint.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid duplication? P.S. sorry I can't vote your answer up, apparently I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: Yes you only could check the answer as correct or not with your reputation.

Comment: The other option that you can do is to hardcode the two URL in your code and check in the code if the localhost connection fails and try with your server connecction. But don' t be ascared with aplicaction replication because is usual to create diferent versions of the products to develop and producction environtments. There are tool like apache ant or apache maven that can help you to create those versions is normal in an application life cycle.

Comment: That sounds like a really good option (a bit messy, but easy). I am using Maven at the moment, and have used Ant in the past, but never really got into that side of it. Guess I'll have to dig a bit deeper. Thanks very much for your help :)